Conflict org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer & 'org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.kafka.TracingKafkaProducer'
I migrate springboot from 2.5 to 2.7 but i encountered this error during th deploy:
**Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'kafkaMigrationProducer' is expected to be of type 'org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer' but was actually of type 'org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.kafka.TracingKafkaProducer'
**
Dependencies:
<parent>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>2.7.0</version>
<relativePath />
</parent>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth</artifactId>
<version>3.1.0</version>
<type>pom</type>
<scope>import</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
<version>2.9.0</version>
</dependency>

Any solution to resolve this conflict ?

Too little information in your question. Please add your actual pom, generally these issues come from incompatible versions of jars. You are using Spring Cloud and Spring Boot, Spring Cloud versions are strictly tied to certain Spring Boot versions. So you cannot just upgrade Spring Boot when using Spring Cloud. You also fixed the spring-kafka version (I would ditch the <version> tag and let Spring Boot manage a compatible version instead).

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
